# How to make scanner accept constant input

Tags: java

I'm pretty new to Java, and would like to know how to make scanner accept input whenever I offer it some, while everything else still working. I've tried to use a while loop like this

```
Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);

while(scanner.hasNext()) {
    String next = scanner.next();
}
```

It now accepts input all the time, but nothing else is working. I've tried google searching but cannot find anything that helps me. I know I'm going to be told to read the Java docs, but I don't know what I should be reading there.

Basically what I'm trying to do is a simple command system for my application. I currently have this

```
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
    String next = scanner.next();

    if (next.startsWith("--")) {
        String[] commandLine = next.split("--");
        String command = commandLine[1];

        if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("start")) {
            if (!running) {
                timer.scheduleAtFixedRate(new Listen(), 0, 5000);
                System.out.println("Task started.");
            } else {
                System.err.println("Task is already running!");
            }

        } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("end")) {
            if (running) {
                timer.cancel();
                System.out.println("Task stopped.");
            } else {
                System.err.println("Task is not running!");
            }

        } else if (command.equalsIgnoreCase("exit")) {
            if (running) {
                timer.cancel();
            }

            System.exit(0);
        }
    }
```

Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: So you essentially want multithreading?

Comment: Well I'm not quite sure what that means. I just edited my post, maybe you can my question better now.

Answer (score 0):

As you have noticed, the current thread can't do anything else while waiting for terminal input.

The solution to this problem is multi-threading, which is described in the [`Concurrency`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/index.html) section of [the Java Tutorials](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/).

> *...Concurrency explains how to write applications that perform multiple tasks simultaneously...This lesson introduces the platform's basic concurrency support and summarizes some of the high-level APIs in the java.util.concurrent packages.*

Answer (score 0):

In order to continuously respond to user input while simultaneously performing other tasks, you must listen for user input in a *separate* thread of execution. Try this:

```
final Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
new Thread() {
    public void run() {
        while (true) {
            String next = scanner.next();
            //additional code here...
        }
    }
}.start();
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure how complex you application is but I think you should use producer-consumer patter, check out [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Vrt5LqpH2D0) video or [this](http://java.dzone.com/articles/solving-producer-consumer) article.

The patter works this way.

- There is a queue.
- There are producer threads which gets the task and push it to the queue. in your case they will read input and put them in the queue
- There are consumers threads which reads from the queue and process them. In you case get the input from the queue and process accordingly.

If you only use just basic threads then there will be new thread created everytime you give a command. Whereas with this patter there are only two threads(there can be more but I don't think it is required in your case) who waits when they don't have anything to do.